# how do I run a correct boolean iteration test on this python code? I wish to iterate through the list checking it x is left< and >right

Tags: python, boolean, iteration

```
x = [7,2,9,10,23,5]
left = 3
right = 8
def solution(numbers, left, right):

    for i in y:
        if y (left < x > right ):
            print(bool(x))
        
        else:
            print(bool(x)
```

I was trying to iterate through the list, and achieve a boolean return for each value in x

Comment: What is `y` here?

Comment: Use indices to loop, which allows you to access the next and previous element. Handle the edgecases of first and last element.

Comment: If you really want to check if `x` is greater than both `left` and `right`, it's simpler to figure out which of the two is bigger, then compare each element of `x` to that. Given the names `left` and `right`, I *suspect* you really want to check something like `left < y < right` (where `y` is an element of `x`.)

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood your requirement**, then you need something like this-

```
x = [7,2,9,10,23,5]
left = 3
right = 8

def solution(numbers, left, right):
    result = []
    for i in numbers:
        if left < i > right:
            status = True
        else:
            status = False
        result.append(status)
    return result
print(solution(x, left, right))
```

**Output:**

```
[False, False, True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Note that `left < i > right` is, in fact, legal and equivalent to `left < i and i > right`.

Comment: @chepner yes I know sir, forgot to change that. done editing